# PHP writing to database, discovering what happens

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have this mysql table

****** login_attempts **********

email (varchar 40)

---

attempts (tinyint 1)

---

ipaddress (CHAR 45)

---

I want to write some data to this table with this PHP code, which seems good.

```
$thecols = "(email,attempts,ipaddress)";
$parndata = array(':one'=>'1111',':two'=>2,':three'=>'3');
$bindings = "(:one,:two,:three)";

insertInto($db,'login_attempts',$thecols,$parndata,$bindings);

function insertInto($db,$table,$tablevals,$pars,$forbinds){
 echo "INSERT INTO $table$tablevals VALUES $forbinds";
 echo '<br>';
 try{

    $one = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO $table$tablevals VALUES $forbinds");
    foreach ($pars as $key => $value) {
        $one->bindParam($key,$value);
        //echo $key.','.$value.'<br>';
    }
    if($one->execute()){ return true; }else{ return false; }

 }catch(PDOException $ex){
    throw $ex;
 }catch(Exception $ex){
    throw $ex;
 }
}
```

but the above code writes the data like that

```
email [3]
attempts [3]
ipaddress [3]
```

why this happened ?

Comment: what happens if the email address is longer than 40 characters? (or is perhaps 10 UTF-8 characters, depending on your collation)

Comment: What happens if the user uses an IPv6 IP address (60 characters)?

Comment: Wow yes.So ill make it 60, if i set it 80 there is problem ?  Thanks.

Comment: actually the maximum is only 45, but still..... you get my point `:-)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `PDOStatement::bindParam($param, &$variable)` accepts `$variable` by reference. All parameters are binded to the same `$value` variable which has a value of `3` at the end of `foreach` loop.
Replace `->bindParam($key,$value);` with `->bindValue($key,$value);` to fix an issue.

Comment: Ohhh friend. YES! naivete for me, I had to test before asking.